# How I can aply a filter condition to two colums in a table using M language?

Tags: data-modeling, powerbi, m

In Power BI I have a table with 3 columns as shown below, And I need to remove only the row that apply both (Have the "customer" value repeat) && (have the "Month" value repeat). In order to do that, I need to find an M function because the Power BI interface does not have a function defined, so if there is a way to do it, must be on "Advanced Editor which use "M" language.

Table:

```
I have:
    Customer Month Bill  
      A        1    x
      A        1    x 
      B        1    x 
      B        2    x 
      C        1    x

I want:    
    Customer Month Bill
       A       1     x
       B       1     x
       B       2     x
       C       1     x
```

Comment: In query edit mode, select first two rows and choose "Remove Duplicates" from the context menu. (or Remove Rows -> Remove Duplicates from the Main Toolbar tab)

Comment: The M code is 

    `= Table.Distinct(#"Changed Type", {"Customer", "Month"})`

Comment: (In PowerBI context, M is known as PowerQuery)